# Vite deploying to vercel with client and server dirs not working

Tags: vite, vercel, tsc

I'm trying to deploy to vercel but I've never done with a backend and this time I have 2 directories: server and client. I tried deploying with the client directory but soon found that my backend wasn't running obviously because the run command didn't include it.

After some research, I found that creating a script in the root directory to run both the client and server was possible and after import all backend dependencies to the root package.json and setting up concurrently, I've run into the following deployment issue:

```
sh: tsc: command not found
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 127
```

My fs looks like this:

```
root:
    -client
    -server
    .gitignore
    .env
    .package.json
    .node_modules
    .package-log.json
    .npm-debug.log
```

And this is my root package.json:

```
{
  "name": "finance",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "server": "nodemon --quiet server",
    "build":"cd ./client && npm run build",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",

  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",


  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "helmet": "^6.0.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^7.3.1",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "react-cookie": "^4.1.1",
    "universal-cookie": "^4.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^8.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "@faker-js/faker": "^8.0.2"
  }
}
```

Here's my client package.json as well:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "vite",
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.11",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.11",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^6.0.0",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^6.9.1",
    "@nivo/pie": "^0.83.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.3",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.8",
    "formik": "^2.4.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-cookie": "^4.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.4.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.2",
    "recharts": "^2.7.2",
    "regression": "^2.0.1",
    "universal-cookie": "^4.0.4",
    "yup": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.16.18",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.27",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@types/regression": "^2.0.2",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.35.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^7.0.1",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "vite": "^4.4.4"
  }
}
```

I've tried installing typescript globally via (which didn't work):

```
npm install typescript -g
```

but shouldn't the script I included take care of the issue since the build is happening in the client folder?

```
"build":"cd ./client && npm run build",
```

I'm out of my league here, any help would be great!